# transforming nested dictionaries into various lists

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary of start and end quantities for a warehouse. I would like to graph this data as a stackplot with matplotlib. I need to transform the data so that x values are a list and y values are a list of list. I would like to limit the plot to keys in which the key is less than or equal to the cuttoff date, 'cutoff'. I wrote all the code to do the plot but am having trouble transforming the data from the dictionary to x and y values. In my example, below I manually typed in the values. In the real script, I have a much larger dataset and need a way to actually code the transformation.

```
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = {
    datetime(2015, 1, 19) : {'start qty': 13 , 'end qty': 12},
    datetime(2015, 1, 20) : {'start qty': 10 , 'end qty': 34},
    datetime(2015, 1, 21) : {'start qty': 30 , 'end qty': 35},
    datetime(2015, 1, 22) : {'start qty': 20 , 'end qty': 40},
}

cutoff = datetime(2015, 1, 21)

y = [[13,10,30],[12,34,35]]
x = [datetime(2015, 1, 19), datetime(2015, 1, 20), datetime(2015, 1, 21)]


plt.stackplot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: @dsm I did. Fixed OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the dates just check against your cutoff date:

```
x = [x for x in d if x <= cutoff]
```

For y use the keys:

```
y = [[d[k]['start qty'],d[k]['end qty']] for k in x]
```

If you are creating the dict and the data is ordered use an [orderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) or `sort` `x`.

For your edit:

```
x = [dte for dte in d if dte <= cutoff]
y = [[],[]]
for k in x:
    y[0].append(d[k]["start qty"])
    y[1].append(d[k]["end qty"])
```

Comment: sorting x, makes sense to me, but that leaves y in a random order still. How can I sort both of these together?

Comment: no if you sort x then y will match up, you are using the sorted keys from x to get the y data, you do want them to match up yes?

Comment: my mistake, I was sorting after I defined y. I had to do it first. I think OrderedDict may be a better option so I will look into that.

Comment: yes, if you control that data and it is sequential then you won't have to sort at all using the Orderddict

Comment: Digging in, it looks like the good does not work as  I had hoped. That is a result of my poor choice of numbers (I repeated 30). I updated the OP to clarify. Can you take a look and modify your answer?